# How to scroll ScrollView to particular percentage of text content?

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, scrollview

I am writing a program which manipulates texts.
I need to be able to programmatically scroll the text to some position. 
I have achieved it partially, but the problem is that it does not always work,

The scenario when it sometimes does not work is as follows:

1. From the activity (1) displaying the text user opens another activity (2)for editing some outlined fragments of text (1)
2. When user closes activity (2) activity (1) must be refreshed and scrolled to the position where it was before.

Here is the layout of the view which I need to scroll:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <ScrollView   
      android:id="@+id/ScrollView02"  
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
      android:layout_width="fill_parent">
      <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/layoutAllText"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textSanskrit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="17dip"
             android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
             android:scrollbars="vertical"
              />    
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTranslit"
             android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="15dip"
             android:scrollbars="vertical"
              />            
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTransl1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="15dip"
             android:scrollbars="vertical"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textTransl2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="17dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10px"
            android:paddingRight="6px"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
             android:scrollbars="vertical"
             android:editable = "false"
             android:background = "#000000"

            />      

            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textComment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="17dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10px"
            android:paddingRight="6px"
             android:scrollbars="vertical"
             android:editable = "false"
             android:textColor = "@android:color/white"
             android:background = "#000000"

            />      
            </LinearLayout>
      </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is an extract from the activity which displays the text to be scrolled:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Central.applySharedTheme(this);

        mExtras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mCurrBookID = mExtras.getString("BookID");
        mCurrChapterNum = mExtras.getString("ChapterNum");
        mCurrTextNum = mExtras.getString("TextNum");
        mTranslateMode = mExtras.getBoolean("TranslateMode");

        setContentView(R.layout.text_disp_basic);

        detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
        mTextScroll=(ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView02);

        mGitaDB=Central.mDB;

        String q="("+mGitaDB.COL_TXT_BOOK_ID+"='"+mCurrBookID+"' AND "+mGitaDB.COL_TXT_CHAPTER_NUM+"='"+mCurrChapterNum+"' AND "+mGitaDB.COL_TXT_TEXT_NUM+"='"+mCurrTextNum+"')";
        mCursor = mGitaDB.getdb().query(mGitaDB.TEXTS_TABLE, null, q, null, null, null, null);

        Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Sanskrit2003.ttf");

        mtxtSanskritView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textSanskrit);
        mtxtTranslitView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTranslit);
        mtxtTransl1View =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTransl1);
        mtxtTransl2View =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTransl2);
        mtxtComment=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textComment);

        mtxtSanskritView.setTypeface(face);


    }

    public void onStart()   {
        super.onStart();

        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) FillTextData();
        ShowSanskrit();
        getScrollPos(); 
        Log.v("SCROLL", "onStart - mScrollPercentage="+String.valueOf(mScrollPercentage));
        ScrollTextToCurrentPercentage("OnStart");

    }
    public void onPause()   {
        super.onPause();
        mbFirstCall=true;
        float scroll = getScrollPos(mTextScroll);
        Log.v("SCROLL", "onPause - getScrollPos="+String.valueOf(scroll));

        SharedPreferences LastOpenedScreen = getSharedPreferences(Central.SHARED_PREFS_LASTSCREEN, MODE_PRIVATE);   
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = LastOpenedScreen.edit();   
        prefEditor.putString(Central.SP_LASTSCREEN_BOOKID, mCurrBookID);

        if(!mTranslateMode){
            prefEditor.putString(Central.SP_LASTSCREEN_BCHAPTER+mCurrBookID, mCurrChapterNum);
            prefEditor.putString(Central.SP_LASTSCREEN_BTEXT+mCurrBookID, mCurrTextNum);
            prefEditor.putFloat(Central.SP_LASTSCREEN_SCROLL, scroll);
            Log.v("SCROLL", "onPause - saved scroll="+String.valueOf(scroll));
        }
        else        
        {
            prefEditor.putFloat("TranslateScrollPercentage", scroll);
            Log.v("SCROLL", "onPause - Before Translate scroll="+String.valueOf(scroll));
        }

        prefEditor.commit();  
    }

   public void onResume()
   {     
        super.onResume(); 

        FillTextData();
        getScrollPos();
        Log.v("SCROLL", "onResume - mScrollPercentage="+String.valueOf(mScrollPercentage));
        ScrollTextToCurrentPercentage("onResume");
   }
    private void getScrollPos()
    {
        String sLastBookID, sLastChapter, sLastText;

        SharedPreferences LastOpenedScreen = getSharedPreferences(Central.SHARED_PREFS_LASTSCREEN, MODE_PRIVATE);
        sLastBookID=LastOpenedScreen.getString(Central.SP_LASTSCREEN_BOOKID, "");
        mScrollPercentage=this.ScrollToFloat(mExtras.getLong("Scroll", 0));
        if (sLastBookID.equalsIgnoreCase(this.mCurrBookID))
        {
            //last chapter and text of this book
            sLastChapter=LastOpenedScreen.getString(Central.SP_LASTSCREEN_BCHAPTER+mCurrBookID, "");
            sLastText=LastOpenedScreen.getString(Central.SP_LASTSCREEN_BTEXT+mCurrBookID, "");

            //if this chapter and text are the same as saved last text and chapter, then set scroll
            if (sLastChapter.equals(this.mCurrChapterNum) && sLastText.equals(this.mCurrTextNum) )
                mScrollPercentage=LastOpenedScreen.getFloat(Central.SP_LASTSCREEN_SCROLL, 0);
        }
        //if this activity is called after translate button pressed
        if (mTranslateMode)
        {
            mScrollPercentage=LastOpenedScreen.getFloat("TranslateScrollPercentage", 0);
            Log.v("SCROLL", "getScrollPos - mTranslateMode - mScrollPercentage="+String.valueOf(mScrollPercentage));
        }

        Log.v("SCROLL", "getScrollPos - mScrollPercentage="+String.valueOf(mScrollPercentage));
    }
    private void ScrollTextToCurrentPercentage(String sCallOrigin)
    {
        //scroll to mScrollPercentage position
        mbFirstCall=true;
        mTextScroll=(ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView02);
        int iHeight=mTextScroll.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
        Log.v("SCROLL", "ScrollTextToCurrentPercentage call. height=:"+String.valueOf(iHeight));
        if (iHeight!=0)
        {
            int y=(int)(iHeight*mScrollPercentage);
            mTextScroll.scrollBy(0, y);
            Log.v("SCROLL", "ScrollText scrolled to:"+String.valueOf(y));
        }
        else
        {
            ViewTreeObserver vto = mTextScroll.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    int y=(int)(mTextScroll.getChildAt(0).getHeight()*mScrollPercentage);
                    if (mbFirstCall){
                        mTextScroll.scrollBy(0, y);
                        mbFirstCall=false;
                        Log.v("SCROLL", "ScrollTextToCurrentPercentage scrolled to:"+String.valueOf(y));

                        }
                    }
            });         
        }

    }
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [ljplus.ru](http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/n/e/nepalec/screenshot.jpg))</sub>

On this screenshot you can see that the program scrolled to the right saved position, however, the real position on the screen is different. Toast shows that real scroll is 8% while the one that was saved is 26%. And the last line in the LogCat shows that      mTextScroll.scrollBy(0, y); line in the ScrollTextToCurrentPercentage was executed.

I am stuck on it, can you help me, perhaps I am doing things wrong way due to lack of knowledge and experience.